# Async controller method & Ajax

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have method in my controller like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> GetMenu(int? Current) {
        await Task.Run(() => System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000));
        return "";
    }
```

And I start it with JQuery Ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetMenu","Products")',
        data: "{}",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#menu-container').html(data);
        },

    });
```

And browser freezes for time of GetMenu action being processed.
How can I make this work in the background in non-blocking way?

Comment: I can only propose you to try to remove a line with async:true. Or try to do it with $.post()

Comment: `async : true` is default even if you don't specify it

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

html

```
<pre id="testpre">
not end
</pre>
```

JS

```
$.post("/Home/ProtocolAjaxHandler", {  }, function (data) {
$("#testpre").html("END");
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProtocolAjaxHandler(object _param)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);
    return Json(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make this work in the background in non-blocking way?

As I explain on my blog, [`async` doesn't change the HTTP protocol](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/08/async-doesnt-change-http-protocol.html). Depending on what you're actually trying to do, you could either try SignalR or use a distributed architecture with a reliable queue and separate background process [as I allude to in another post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/returning-early-from-aspnet-requests.html).

Comment: But why does the "browser freeze"? Is that just an unfortunate wording?

Comment: I interpreted it as "the browser doesn't get a response".